# Scroll down to bottom. Then reload page and do it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this simple code, and it's working fine.

```
$("#mydiv").animate({ scrollTop: $('#mydiv')[0].scrollHeight}, 20000)
```

What I would like is to after the bottom has been reached immediately go back to the top of the page and start scrolling down slowly again. How would one achive something like this in JQuery?

Thank you guys!

Comment: You'll need to provide with some HTML markup. This question is too vague without some context.

Comment: Agree with @Stef. Please add some HTML.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to do this. Learn how to use animation callbacks which are explained in the docs

Comment: The other thing I find confusing is that you mention reloading the page, but it sounds like you just want to scroll the contents of the div. Please let us know what exactly you're after. Those two things are quite different.

Comment: I wanna scroll down. Then get back to the top somehow, via refresh or other method and scroll down again. Not sure how to make it clearer :/

Comment: People need to relax on here. The guy is just asking for a way to get back to the top of the page. stop making it complicated and if you know the answer post it. Or if theres a duplicate, then just flag it as a duplicate and give him the link.

Answer (score 0):

you can jump back to the top of your page using the following javascript function:

```
function jump(elementId){
    var location = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, location);                        
}
```

just use the `id` of some element at the top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do and what "reload" means but here is a quick snippet to get you started:

[**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/263/Page-loop-scrolling-and-scaning)

As you can see its configurable and easy to understand:

```
  $(function() {


  var pageScan = {
      speed : 10000,
      loop  : true,
      delayRestart : 1000, 
      start : function(){
          pageHeight = $('body').height() - window.innerHeight;
          pageScan.proc(pageHeight);
      },
      proc  : function(to){
          $("body").animate(
              {scrollTop: to}, 
               pageScan.speed,
               "linear",
               function(){
                  if (pageScan.loop) {
                      setTimeout(function() {
                          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                          pageScan.start();
                      }, pageScan.delayRestart);
                  }
          });
      }
  };

  pageScan.start();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do something easier like this:

```
(function (){
    var div = $('#myDiv'),
        infiniteScroll = function () {

            //---gets the bottom of the page value
            var bottomHeight = div[0].scrollHeight; 

            var callback1 = function () {   
                //once it gets into this callback function 
                //it resets the position to zero

                div.scrollTop(0);

                //invokes again the function infinite scroll
                infiniteScroll();
            };

            div.animate({scrollTop:bottomHeight},20000,callback1)
    };
    //starts the function for the very first time
    infiniteScroll();

})();
```

I created a codepen so you can see it working and play with it:

http://codepen.io/dieggger/pen/VLoZWv?editors=101